# cocos2d improve the preloader

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to improve the preloader where I preload all my assets by collecting everything like sprites, plists and sounds in one huge plist. Is it possible?
Or collecting everything in a service for example where in the future i can load it from internet? Basically how can I create a plist which will contain sprites, sounds and other plist so I can optimized my preload scene instead of writing 100 lines of code ? I appreciated your time and effort.

Comment: I don't think you want "yes" as an answer, do you? Please ask more specifically what you need to know.